# mySQL: return the remaining on a parent/child relationship

Tags: mysql

I have an `article` table. 1 `article` can be a sequel of another `article`, therefore the `parent_id` column.

```
id   | title  | parent_id
---------------------------------------------
62   | Blues  | 61
74   | Folk   | 61
14   | Pop    | 61
61   | Easy   | NULL
45   | Country| NULL
```

Basically, I have a one level parent/child relationship.

[image]

If I select the parent, I want to return the children (that query is an easy one).

And if I select a child, I want to return the parent and the remaining children (that query I cannot achieve)

So, If I select `61` (a parent), I want to return the remaining (the children), like so:

```
id   | title  | id | title
---------------------------------------------
61   | Easy   | 14 | Pop
61   | Easy   | 62 | Blues
61   | Easy   | 74 | Folk
```

And, if I select `14` (a child), I want to return the remaining (the parent + remaining children), like so:

```
id   | title  | id | title
---------------------------------------------
14   | Pop   | 61 | Easy
14   | Pop   | 62 | Blues
14   | Pop   | 74 | Folk
```

And, if I select `45`, I want to return the remaining (in this case, there is no children to return), like so:

```
id   | title   | id   | title
---------------------------------------------
45   | Country | NULL | NULL
```

Im looking for a query that will return the record selected and the remaining ones. Is this feasible with one query? Do I need to use a UNION?

Searching here, I was able to create the first query:

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.title, c.id, c.title
FROM
    article p
    LEFT JOIN article c ON p.id = c.parent_id
WHERE
    p.id = 61
```

Comment: Tip: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: @Strawberry it was put for testing purposes... I've edited the question to prevent distractions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the same table `article` with conditions that:

1. Row may be child
2. Row may be parent
3. Row may be sibling

But remember to filter the same child (when p.id=c.id).

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.title, c.id, c.title
FROM
    article p
    LEFT JOIN article c ON p.parent_id=c.parent_id OR p.parent_id=c.id OR c.parent_id=p.id
WHERE
    p.id = 61 AND p.id!=c.id
ORDER BY c.id ASC
```

[Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vmz4NWDx41VScaq8NqjJB6/0)

Comment: If I choose a record that contains no children, let's say `45`, then it returns nothing. It should return at least the record `45`

Comment: ok, I've changed `p.id != c.id` TO `NOT p.id <=> c.id` and now I'm able to select records with no children

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Form input id, retrieve the row, and Check parent_id is NULL or interger. Then form different queries to achieve your objective.

`IF parent_id IS NULL.`  take the MySQL id.

```
SELECT * FROM article p where parent_id = <id>;

ELSE

SELECT * FROM article p where (parent_id = <parent_id> OR id = <parent_id>) AND id != <id>;
```

Example : 
1. if you pass id as 61 then,
  SELECT * FROM article where id = 61;

Here parent_id is NULL so you have to run the query,

SELECT * FROM article p where parent_id = 61;

2. if you pass id as 14 then,
   SELECT * FROM article where id = 14;

   Here parent_id is NOT NULL, parent_id value is 61.

   So your query is : SELECT * FROM article p where (parent_id = 61 OR id = 61) AND id != 14;

I hope you understood

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM article c 
  JOIN article p 
    ON p.id = c.parent_id 
  JOIN article s 
    ON s.parent_id = c.parent_id 
   AND s.id <> c.id 
 WHERE c.id = 14
 UNION
SELECT p.* 
  FROM article c 
  JOIN article p 
    ON p.id = c.parent_id 
 WHERE c.id = 14;
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | title | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
| 62 | Blues |        61 |
| 74 | Folk  |        61 |
| 61 | Easy  |      NULL |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: the record `14` is not return. I want to return the main record (even if the main record as no children)

Comment: Also, if I select `61` nothing is return.

Comment: I'm going to leave those aspects as an exercise for the reader.